# couldn't open logictech joystick

Tags: ros, turtlebot, logitech, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bought a Logitech F710 joystick to run the turtlebot.  installed
turtlebot_teleop_joystick
says can't open joytick /dev/input/js0
I drove with keyboard OK.

Ubuntu 10.4 electric ROS

Thanks,

Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45264/couldn%27t-open-logictech-joystick/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No error now, so it's something else I've forgot.  Gotta find my notes...
Alan

---

Originally posted by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) with karma: 191 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1